# How to count number of same items in array

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have array named `$result` that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [items_to_give] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 188530170
                    [classid] => 469643069
                    [assetid] => 5036379364
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => StatTrak™ AK-47 | Vulcan (Field-Tested)
                    [market_name] => StatTrak™ AK-47 | Vulcan (Field-Tested)
                    [name] => StatTrak™ AK-47 | Vulcan
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhjxszJemkV086jloKOhcj5Nr_Yg2YfvZcg0rmXrI2n31ex8ks9Zjz2JIKdcVA4ZArRqVm-wLzn1sC8uJnMwWwj5HcoJjKuZA
                )

        )

    [items_to_receive] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 721248158
                    [assetid] => 5081796191
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Chroma Case Key
                    [market_name] => Chroma Case Key
                    [name] => Chroma Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiezrLVYygaCYdDlB79_mwdKIlq-tY-LUlzgB6sYm27-W8dvx0Vey_0ZrY3ezetEQGWlygA
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 721248158
                    [assetid] => 5081796157
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Chroma Case Key
                    [market_name] => Chroma Case Key
                    [name] => Chroma Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiezrLVYygaCYdDlB79_mwdKIlq-tY-LUlzgB6sYm27-W8dvx0Vey_0ZrY3ezetEQGWlygA
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 927007517
                    [assetid] => 5081796041
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Chroma 2 Case Key
                    [market_name] => Chroma 2 Case Key
                    [name] => Chroma 2 Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOie3rKFRh16PKd2pDvozixtSOwaP2ar7SlzIA6sEo2rHCpdyhjAGxr0A6MHezetG0RZXdTA
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 927007517
                    [assetid] => 5081796013
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Chroma 2 Case Key
                    [market_name] => Chroma 2 Case Key
                    [name] => Chroma 2 Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOie3rKFRh16PKd2pDvozixtSOwaP2ar7SlzIA6sEo2rHCpdyhjAGxr0A6MHezetG0RZXdTA
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 721248158
                    [assetid] => 5081795981
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Chroma Case Key
                    [market_name] => Chroma Case Key
                    [name] => Chroma Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiezrLVYygaCYdDlB79_mwdKIlq-tY-LUlzgB6sYm27-W8dvx0Vey_0ZrY3ezetEQGWlygA
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 506856210
                    [assetid] => 5081796124
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Huntsman Case Key
                    [market_name] => Huntsman Case Key
                    [name] => Huntsman Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOienreFAyh6TKKWsRuNnvzYKPwKeiYr7VwT5Usccj07HC99ym2Vbm_xE5MXezetFgrl7eog
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 506856210
                    [assetid] => 5081796073
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Huntsman Case Key
                    [market_name] => Huntsman Case Key
                    [name] => Huntsman Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOienreFAyh6TKKWsRuNnvzYKPwKeiYr7VwT5Usccj07HC99ym2Vbm_xE5MXezetFgrl7eog
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 721248158
                    [assetid] => 5081795950
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Chroma Case Key
                    [market_name] => Chroma Case Key
                    [name] => Chroma Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiezrLVYygaCYdDlB79_mwdKIlq-tY-LUlzgB6sYm27-W8dvx0Vey_0ZrY3ezetEQGWlygA
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1293510722
                    [assetid] => 5081795507
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Shadow Case Key
                    [market_name] => Shadow Case Key
                    [name] => Shadow Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiePrKF4wi6aaIGwStN_jl4bSzvXwMO6AwDlSvsYoiOiZ8dij3QbtqkU9ZnezetFWWxusZg
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1432182528
                    [assetid] => 5081795775
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [market_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiev1ZVNkgqeRdWUV7o3kltLdzvOjauqCwDlUupAj0-rD843zjAbt_hVtMDjtZNjCJHQgy4g
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1432182528
                    [assetid] => 5081795823
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [market_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiev1ZVNkgqeRdWUV7o3kltLdzvOjauqCwDlUupAj0-rD843zjAbt_hVtMDjtZNjCJHQgy4g
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1293510722
                    [assetid] => 5081795867
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Shadow Case Key
                    [market_name] => Shadow Case Key
                    [name] => Shadow Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiePrKF4wi6aaIGwStN_jl4bSzvXwMO6AwDlSvsYoiOiZ8dij3QbtqkU9ZnezetFWWxusZg
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1432182528
                    [assetid] => 5081794936
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [market_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiev1ZVNkgqeRdWUV7o3kltLdzvOjauqCwDlUupAj0-rD843zjAbt_hVtMDjtZNjCJHQgy4g
                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1432182528
                    [assetid] => 5081794899
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [market_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiev1ZVNkgqeRdWUV7o3kltLdzvOjauqCwDlUupAj0-rD843zjAbt_hVtMDjtZNjCJHQgy4g
                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 927007517
                    [assetid] => 5081795047
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Chroma 2 Case Key
                    [market_name] => Chroma 2 Case Key
                    [name] => Chroma 2 Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOie3rKFRh16PKd2pDvozixtSOwaP2ar7SlzIA6sEo2rHCpdyhjAGxr0A6MHezetG0RZXdTA
                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1293510722
                    [assetid] => 5081795024
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Shadow Case Key
                    [market_name] => Shadow Case Key
                    [name] => Shadow Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiePrKF4wi6aaIGwStN_jl4bSzvXwMO6AwDlSvsYoiOiZ8dij3QbtqkU9ZnezetFWWxusZg
                )

            [16] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1432182528
                    [assetid] => 5081795169
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [market_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiev1ZVNkgqeRdWUV7o3kltLdzvOjauqCwDlUupAj0-rD843zjAbt_hVtMDjtZNjCJHQgy4g
                )

            [17] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1432182528
                    [assetid] => 5081795138
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [market_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiev1ZVNkgqeRdWUV7o3kltLdzvOjauqCwDlUupAj0-rD843zjAbt_hVtMDjtZNjCJHQgy4g
                )

            [18] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1293510722
                    [assetid] => 5081795468
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Shadow Case Key
                    [market_name] => Shadow Case Key
                    [name] => Shadow Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiePrKF4wi6aaIGwStN_jl4bSzvXwMO6AwDlSvsYoiOiZ8dij3QbtqkU9ZnezetFWWxusZg
                )

            [19] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1432182528
                    [assetid] => 5081795274
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [market_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiev1ZVNkgqeRdWUV7o3kltLdzvOjauqCwDlUupAj0-rD843zjAbt_hVtMDjtZNjCJHQgy4g
                )

            [20] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1432182528
                    [assetid] => 5081795242
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [market_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiev1ZVNkgqeRdWUV7o3kltLdzvOjauqCwDlUupAj0-rD843zjAbt_hVtMDjtZNjCJHQgy4g
                )

            [21] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 992003613
                    [assetid] => 5081795110
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Falchion Case Key
                    [market_name] => Falchion Case Key
                    [name] => Falchion Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOieLreQE4g_CfI20b7tjmzNXYxK-hYOmHkj9QvpIg2OyVpdus0AW1_EQ9MnezetGj61oqPA
                )

            [22] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1432182528
                    [assetid] => 5081795076
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [market_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiev1ZVNkgqeRdWUV7o3kltLdzvOjauqCwDlUupAj0-rD843zjAbt_hVtMDjtZNjCJHQgy4g
                )

            [23] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1432182528
                    [assetid] => 5081795197
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [market_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiev1ZVNkgqeRdWUV7o3kltLdzvOjauqCwDlUupAj0-rD843zjAbt_hVtMDjtZNjCJHQgy4g
                )

            [24] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1432182528
                    [assetid] => 5081795002
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [market_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiev1ZVNkgqeRdWUV7o3kltLdzvOjauqCwDlUupAj0-rD843zjAbt_hVtMDjtZNjCJHQgy4g
                )

            [25] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1432182528
                    [assetid] => 5081794970
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [market_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiev1ZVNkgqeRdWUV7o3kltLdzvOjauqCwDlUupAj0-rD843zjAbt_hVtMDjtZNjCJHQgy4g
                )

            [26] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1432182528
                    [assetid] => 5081794827
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [market_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiev1ZVNkgqeRdWUV7o3kltLdzvOjauqCwDlUupAj0-rD843zjAbt_hVtMDjtZNjCJHQgy4g
                )

            [27] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1432182528
                    [assetid] => 5081794860
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [market_name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [name] => Revolver Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiev1ZVNkgqeRdWUV7o3kltLdzvOjauqCwDlUupAj0-rD843zjAbt_hVtMDjtZNjCJHQgy4g
                )

            [28] => Array
                (
                    [instanceid] => 143865972
                    [classid] => 1293510722
                    [assetid] => 5081794734
                    [amount] => 1
                    [market_hash_name] => Shadow Case Key
                    [market_name] => Shadow Case Key
                    [name] => Shadow Case Key
                    [icon_url] => -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXX7gNTPcUxuxpJSXPbQv2S1MDeXkh6LBBOiePrKF4wi6aaIGwStN_jl4bSzvXwMO6AwDlSvsYoiOiZ8dij3QbtqkU9ZnezetFWWxusZg
                )

        )

)
```

How can i count how many times there is word "key" in $result[items_to_receive][$key][name] ?

Comment: Origin of array is by coding, json, xml, text, db query or what?

Comment: just use a `foreach` loop, initialize a counter from zero, then increment if it has occurence using `strpos`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a foreach look to loop through all that array and then test the 'name' field for the value `key` using the case insensitive function `stripos`

```
$key_count = 0;
foreach ($result['items_to_receive'] as $item ) {
    if ( stripos( $item['name'], 'key' ) ) {
        $key_count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add another bracket after 'key' . It works thanks

Comment: hmm foreach loop interesting. Thanks Riggs you're the best!

Answer (score 2):

If your PHP version is 5.5 or above, you can use `array_column` along with `preg_grep`:

```
$totKey = count
(
    preg_grep
    (
        '/.*Key.*/',
        array_column( $result['items_to_receive'], 'name' )
    )
);
```

Otherwise, you have to perform a foreach loop through all `$result['items_to_receive']` items and check `name` value.